# Angular 2 router i18n url

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-router

I'm currently developing a web app based on Angular 2.1.0.

I received some instructions by the SEO specialist regarding the way I need to set the different urls (based on the language used), for example :

```
http://www.example.com/actualite // french version
http://www.example.com/en/news // english version
```

I haven't seen a part in the docs where this kind of problem is discussed. Is there a solution to my problem ?

Thanks for your time and help !

Comment: Just create 2(or more) root paths and add childrens.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I get what you mean. I don't know if it was clear enough in my post, but the 2 links are supposed to be the same page.

http://www.example.com/actualite (french) == http://www.example.com/en/news (english)

I considered using a parent '/en' for the english versions but I cannot figure out how to easily change the links.

For example [routerLink]="['actualite'] should be (ideally dynamically) changed to [routerLink]=['en/news'] when the english version is set.